# how to load txt contains different columns with different rows

Tags: matlab

I have `txt` that contains different columns. For example, the following txt has

```
1 2
1 2
1 2
1 2
1 2
1 2 3 4
1 2 3 4
1 2 3 4
1 2 3 4
```

the first column is ones, therefore I'm expecting the output to be for the first column is ones. When I use `load`, it throws out this error

```
Error using load
Number of columns on line 6 of ASCII file test.txt must be the same as previous lines.
```

I used `importdata` but the output is

```
 1
 1
 1
 1
 1
 1
 3
 1
 3
 1
 3
 1
 3
```

Comment: I don't get that output when I use `importdata`. Can you show your code?

Comment: without any additional parameters, importdata will read it columnwise, and create a column vector

Comment: `A = importdata('test.txt');
B = A(:,1)`

Comment: @MikhailGenkin, what are the parameters should I pass?

Answer (score 2):

May be this is not the best approach, but it is still short. 
If your file contains less then 1000000 lines,you can use:

```
a=importdata('1.txt','\n',1000000)
```

As a result, `a` will be cell array, with number of cells equal to number of you lines (rows). Now, say, if you want to obtain 3rd line, just use:

```
b=str2num(a{3})
```

`b` is a row vector - the third line in your txt file.

Edit: if you want to extract the 1st column, use for loop:

```
a=importdata('1.txt','\n',1000000);
b=zeros(1,numel(a));  % b will be first column
for i=1:numel(a)       % loop throw rows 
    p=str2num(a{i});   % obtain row #i
    b(i)=p(1);            % b(i)=first element
end
```

May be there is a better way. This solution is convenient for working with rows,
I didn't notice, that you want to obtain column

Comment: unfortunately I don't the size. It varies depending on how long the experiment is running.

Comment: Just write some very big number, which will be greater then your actual number of lines anyway.

Comment: how to extract an entire column, assuming the column exists in both before and after changing the column numbers (see the first and second columns in my example)? say the first one.

Comment: which version of Matlab you are using? I'm getting an error.

Comment: Sorry, there was a mistake. Please try right now - should work. My version is 2012a

Answer (score 2):

In Matlab R2014b

```
c=csvread('test.txt')

c =

     1     2     0     0
     1     2     0     0
     1     2     0     0
     1     2     0     0
     1     2     0     0
     1     2     3     4
     1     2     3     4
     1     2     3     4
     1     2     3     4
```

Comment: I don't have R2014b. I have R2014a

Comment: `csvread` dates back to R2006a: http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/csvread.html

Comment: Well I'm not getting what you got.

Comment: Confirmed that `csvread` behavior differs between R2014a and R2014b; in the earlier release the output is a 1 dimensional vector.

Answer (score 2):

`csvread` for some reason gives different behavior between R2014a and R2014b with no documentation for the change. Use `dlmread` instead:

```
dlmread('input.txt')
```

Output gives:

```
ans =
     1     2     0     0
     1     2     0     0
     1     2     0     0
     1     2     0     0
     1     2     0     0
     1     2     0     0
     1     2     0     0
     1     2     0     0
     1     2     0     0
     1     2     0     0
     1     2     0     0
     1     2     3     4
     1     2     3     4
     1     2     3     4
     1     2     3     4
     1     2     3     4
```

Answer (score 1):

Assuming your file contains only numeric values, you can parse it into cell array like this:

```
% Read full file
str = fileread('A.txt'); 

% Convert text in a cell array of strings  
c = strsplit(str, '\n');

% Convert 'string' elements to 'double' 
n = cellfun(@str2num, c, 'UniformOutput', false);
```

You can then access individual lines (as an array of double) like this:

```
>> n{1}

ans =

     1     2

>> n{7}

ans =

     1     2     3    4
```

PS: This is a duplicate of my answer to [How to load a text file in Matlab when the number of values in every line are different](https://stackoverflow.com/a/28692329/684399)